# SMIME with BIO, char * and binary data

Tags: c, openssl, pkcs#7, smime

**The problem**

1- I'd like to create a MIME message. Something like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="---12345"

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

---12345
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the plain text

---12345
Content-Type: application/pdf

>> PDF binary code here <<

---12345
```

2- Then i need to pass it to the OpenSSL functions in the form of `BIO * data`.

```
PKCS7 *PKCS7_sign(..., ..., ..., BIO *data, ...);
```

**The first approach**

Load the plain text and attachment data from the filesystem and assign it to `char * data`, manipulate the data to add the respective MIME headers, finally assign it to `BIO * memoryBIO` with `BIO_puts(memoryBIO, data);`.

But this approach doesnt work because the binary data contains "\0"(NULL) which wont go well with `char` type.

**The second approach**

Assign plain text and attachment to a `BIO` *each* and then "concatenate" them. But couldn't find a way to do this.

**Conclusion**

I'd like to know if there is a way to accomplish such feat.
I'd also like to avoid using intermediary files and build everything in-memory.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of [openssl smime](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/smime.html) command line utility?

Comment: When you have embedded nulls, you can't use [`BIO_puts`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_puts.html) as you observed. Instead, you use [`BIO_write`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_puts.html), which takes both a pointer and a length. You have to use the right tool for the job. You can't pound that square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Or if you have everything in one buffer (and won't further modify it) create a memBIO using that buffer with `BIO_new_mem_buf`. Also note it's fragile to put binary data like a PDF in a multipart; CTE:base64 would be better.

Comment: @jww I see, i will use BIO_write for sure on a sidenote when i load a file to char *, while inspecting it, i see that it only holds data until a null is encountered, which splits data.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the memory buffer suggestion, i already use it.  Initially, i didn't want to base64 encode the data because the signing and encryption functions already do that for me, and i know it will increase the size by 30%. Do you think  i should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following jww's suggestion, what i ended up using is `BIO_write();`.

```
BIO * inBIO = NULL;
std::vector<unsigned char> data = GetData();
inBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_write(inBIO, data.data(), data.size());
```

Again thanks to jww for this answer and for all the other answers regarding OpenSSL in SO, you've helped me a great deal.